# zsh scripting exit npm run keypress

Tags: webpack, scripting, zsh

I have a script I made in zshrc functions to install laravel and the equivalent of make:auth new commands. I ended the script with npm run watch and this leaves me in webpack. Control + C will exit back to zsh. I want to put this in the script so that when the npm commands are done the equivalent of control c is executed. How can I do this?

Comment: The benefit of the "watch" script is that it watches for changes and updates your front end immediately, without needing to re-run the build. If you don't want to "watch", why wouldn't you just run "build"? That would exit immediately without needing to add a command to exit to your zsh script.

Comment: @JBallin I do want it to "watch", but I am trying to minimize the number of commands that I have to manually run. I wrote a script for it to do this as this is the desired default behavior. Everything works fine, but when the "npm run watch" command is executed my script ends. Leaving me in the webpack screen on zsh. No problem, I can hit Ctrl+C to exit webpack, but since it is also a repetitive task, I'd like to end my script with an additional command to send Ctrl+C to exit webpack also. Does this make sense?

Comment: I still don't understand. If you're exiting "watch" (what you're referring to as the "webpack screen"), you aren't watching. It sounds like you need to open a new terminal tab/window (that's what I do - note that you can use applescript on a mac for this if desired) or figure out a way to make it run as a background process (seems overly complicated). If you sometimes don't want to "watch", why not either create a second script that runs "build" or take a parameter/flag that will change the default behavior to use "build" instead of "watch"?

Comment: Ahhhhh..... when I hit Control+C that exits webpack and therefore ends "watch"? I thought I could exit to zsh to run some php artisan commands and that watch stays in effect permanently. That's why I wanted to issue Control+C to return to the zsh where I could continue with artisan commands.

Comment: That's right. You can test it yourself by ending the process, making changes, and seeing if they're reflected on the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "watch" script will only watch for changes if you leave the webpack process running in that Terminal tab/window. You'll need to run the "build" script if you want it to exit after building.

I suggest you open a new Terminal tab after running your zsh script, where you can run other commands. This a common workflow. A more advanced workflow would use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) to run multiple processes in one tab.